# Scrapy: returns empty list

Tags: python, scrapy

So, I was trying to create an olx **scraper** and have encountered a hitch, I get a response possible from shell but dont get anything in the pipeline array

My **scraper**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from olx.items import OlxItem


class ElectronicsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "electronics"
    allowed_domains = ["www.olx.in"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.olx.in/computers-accessories/',
        'https://www.olx.in/tv-video-audio/',
        'https://www.olx.in/games-entertainment/'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_css=('.pageNextPrev',)),
             callback="parse_item",
             follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item_links = response.css('.large > .detailsLink::attr(href)').extract()
        for a in item_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(a, callback=self.parse_detail_page)

    def parse_detail_page(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract()[0].strip()
        price = response.css('.pricelabel > strong::text').extract()[0]

        item = OlxItem()
        item['title'] = title
        item['price'] = price
        item['url'] = response.url
        yield item
```

The response without logs with the command: *scrapy crawl --nolog electronics* is simply nothing, which indicates that an empty list is being passed in the item pipeline when seen logs are something like this

```
...
2020-07-14 18:43:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
...
```

Comment: Can I ask what the goal of the scraping is ? I see that there are many items on each page requiring clicking the more button to reveal their links. This requires some reverse engineering to get those links on each individual page. I actually can't replicated your CSS selector choices on the page which is probably why you're not getting what you want. Have you tried these selectors out in the shell ?

Answer (score 0):

I have change the parse_detail_page as parse.please see the [doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    # from olx.items import OlxItem
    
    
    class ElectronicsSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "electronics"
        allowed_domains = ["www.olx.in"]
        start_urls = [
            'https://www.olx.in/computers-accessories/',
            'https://www.olx.in/tv-video-audio/',
            'https://www.olx.in/games-entertainment/'
        ]
    
        rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_css=('.pageNextPrev',)),
                 callback="parse_item",
                 follow=True),)
    
        def parse_item(self, response):
            item_links = response.css('.large > .detailsLink::attr(href)').extract()
            for a in item_links:
                yield scrapy.Request(a)
    
        def parse(self, response):
            title = response.css('span._2tW1I::text').extract()[0].strip()
            price = response.css('span._89yzn::text').extract()[0]
            print()
            print()
            yield {
                'title': title,
                'price': price,
                'url': response.url
            }
Output here

    {'title': 'Fiber splicing machine', 'price': '₹ 1,55,000', 'url': 'https://www.olx.in/computers-laptops_c1505', 'field_name_for_your_processed_files': []}
    2020-07-14 22:04:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.olx.in/tv-video-audio_c1523> (referer: None)
    
    
    2020-07-14 22:04:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.olx.in/tv-video-audio_c1523>
    {'title': 'Digidesign 003 sound card', 'price': '₹ 35,000', 'url': 'https://www.olx.in/tv-video-audio_c1523', 'field_name_for_your_processed_files': []}
    2020-07-14 22:04:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.olx.in/games-entertainment_c93> (referer: None)
    
    
    2020-07-14 22:04:30 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.olx.in/games-entertainment_c93>
    {'title': 'ps4,ps3,xbox sales and services(S-GAMERSHOP)', 'price': '₹ 19,000', 'url': 'https://www.olx.in/games-entertainment_c93', 'field_name_for_your_processed_files': []}
```